# The error of sstableloader

Tags: java, cassandra

I try to load data to a Cassandra cluster using the sstableloader.
The sstableloader shows the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
        at java.nio.HeapByteBuffer.<init>(HeapByteBuffer.java:57)
        at java.nio.ByteBuffer.allocate(ByteBuffer.java:335)
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.BufferType$1.allocate(BufferType.java:28)
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.util.RandomAccessReader.allocateBuffer(RandomAccessReader.java:69)
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.util.RandomAccessReader.<init>(RandomAccessReader.java:62)
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.util.RandomAccessReader.open(RandomAccessReader.java:103)
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.util.RandomAccessReader.open(RandomAccessReader.java:92)
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.util.RandomAccessReader.open(RandomAccessReader.java:87)
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.util.BufferedSegmentedFile.getSegment(BufferedSegmentedFile.java:60)
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.util.SegmentedFile$SegmentIterator.next(SegmentedFile.java:271)
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.util.SegmentedFile$SegmentIterator.next(SegmentedFile.java:252)
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.format.big.BigTableReader.getPosition(BigTableReader.java:184)
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.format.SSTableReader.getPosition(SSTableReader.java:1558)
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.format.SSTableReader.getPositionsForRanges(SSTableReader.java:1489)
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.SSTableLoader$1.accept(SSTableLoader.java:128)
        at java.io.File.list(File.java:1161)
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.SSTableLoader.openSSTables(SSTableLoader.java:79)
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.SSTableLoader.stream(SSTableLoader.java:161)
        at org.apache.cassandra.tools.BulkLoader.main(BulkLoader.java:97)
```

If i understand the situation It needs to increase MAX_HEAP_SIZE. How can I do it for sstableloader?

It sounds not very optimistic - "/usr/bin/sstableloader still has a hard coded -Mx256M that can't be easily overridden". https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-7385

Thanks.

I edited bin/sstableloader to set MAX_HEAP_SIZE="16GB". After it sstatableloader works.

Comment: see https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-7385

Comment: The relevant part in the issue is: "We are now employing this workaround before starting an sstableloader run:
`sed -i -e 's/-Xmx256M/-Xmx8G/g' /usr/bin/sstableloader`". That'll change the max heap from 256m to 8G.

Comment: I've seen it, but I don't understand how it may help me.

Comment: Do you know what `sed` is or are you from the windows fraction?

Comment: Now I understand, we change the utility using the text editor. Is it correct?

Comment: Correct. The command uses `sed` ("streaming editor") to look for every occurrence of "-Xmx256M" and replaces it with "-Xmx8G" ('g' at the end for "global replace"). After that you'll have a patched version of sstableloader.

Comment: @Dirk Lachowski, thank you. It's really simple. sstableloader is usually bash script wrapper.

Comment: Please add the solution...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Cassandra v.2.2.4 you may edit sstableloader file, using vi, nano etc., to set MAX_HEAP_SIZE="16GB"
or:

```
sed -i -e 's/MAX_HEAP_SIZE="256M"/MAX_HEAP_SIZE="16G"/g' sstableloader
```

Answer (score 2):

The sstableloader.sh contains the following line in code

```
if [ "x$MAX_HEAP_SIZE" = "x" ];
   ...
```

Thus, put MAX_HEAP_SIZE in front of your sstableloader command would set environment variable temporary and been recognised by sstableloader:

```
MAX_HEAP_SIZE="16G" sstableloader -d node /file/path
```